# I'm trying to create a global variable in express (also using mongoose), but the app keeps deleting the variable when the page is refreshed

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm working on an e-commerce project.  I'm trying to create a shopping cart within the app so that people don't accidentally access another user's data in the Mongo database.  To do this, I tried setting up a variable as `res.locals.cart`.  This didn't work because I found out from the docs that `res.locals` expires in each new page.

My next idea was to create an anonymous shopping cart each time app.js started and store it in the global `app.locals` object.  This does work, and in the following code, you can see it returns the model of the shopping cart.  But after that, it's undefined as soon as I refresh or go to a new page as seen by `console.log`.  Why is it doing that?  How can I make it so that my data stays across the whole app?  And I need it to be a variable, so that it changes for each new user.  If there are also any NPM packages that solve this problem, that would be helpful to know.

```js
app.locals.cart = Cart.create({}, function (err, newCart) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(newCart);
    return newCart
    
  }
  
});

app.get('/cart', function (req, res) {
  console.log(app.locals.cart);
  res.render('cart')
  
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**This is not the best practive**, but, if you still want to do it, than **this is an example code** you can see:

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.locals.cart = [];

const item = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Testing'
}

const addToCart = function(req, res, next) {
  const { username } = req.body;
  // req.body.username just for identifier
  // you can change it with user id from token or token or whatever you want
  if(typeof app.locals.cart[username] === 'undefined') {
    app.locals.cart[username] = [];
  }
  // add item to cart by username / identifier
  app.locals.cart[username].push(item);

  next();
}

// or if you want to use this add to global, than you can use this middleware
// and now, you can see
// app.use(addToCart);

app.post('/', addToCart, (req, res, next) => {
  // console.log
  const { username } = req.body;
  console.log(app.locals.cart[username])
  res.send(app.locals.cart[username]);
})


app.get('/:username', (req, res, next) => {
  const { username } = req.params;
  console.log(app.locals.cart[username]);
  res.send(app.locals.cart[username]);
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is up');
})
```

I hope it's can help you .

Answer (score -1):

I think the way you are trying is not a best practice.
Instead of using the `locals` try a different approach.

Creating a cart for each user in the database will be better.
You can link the card with the user. And whenever a user makes a request you fetch the cart from DB and do whatever you want.

To do that, you can add a user property to the Cart Schema. Whenever a user signs up, create a cart for it in the DB. When the user checkouts the cart, save the products in the card as another Document, let say an Order in the Orders Collection and clear the cart for future usage.

Answer (score -1):

QUICK DIGEST:

Store any data from Mongoose onto a variable on your middleware and then have that variable read by app.locals or res.locals.  The reason for this is because app.locals is changing and your middleware variable isn't, which lets it be read the same way every time.  Example:

```
res.locals.data = middleware.var;
//or
app.locals.data = middleware.var;

Model.findById("model-id", function (err, noErr) {
    if (!err) {
        middleware.var = noErr //data retrieved from callback being passed into middleware.var

    }

});
```

Here's what I discovered.  My code didn't work because Express refuses to store data directly from a Mongoose function.  I discovered this by console.logging the data inside the function and again outside it.  I'm not sure why Express refuses to take data this way, but that's what was happening.

```
Cart.create({}, function (err, newCart) {
  if (!err) {
    app.locals.cart = newCart;
    console.log(app.locals.cart);
    //Returns Mongoose model

  }

});

console.log(app.locals.cart);
//Now returns undefined
```

I solved this by storing the value to a variable in my middleware object called `mids`.

Here's the code on my app.js:

```
mids.anonymousCart();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.userTrue = req.user;
  res.locals.cart = mids.cart;
  next();

});
```

And here's the code on my middleware file:

```
var mids = {
  anonymous_id: undefined,
  cart: []

};

mids.anonymousCart = function () {
  if (typeof mids.anonymous_id === 'undefined') {
    Cart.create({}, function (err, newCart) {
      if (!err) {
        mids.anonymous_id = newCart._id.toString();

        Cart.findById(mids.anonymous_id).populate('items').exec(function (err, cartReady) {
          if (!err) {
            mids.cart = cartReady;

          }

        });

      }

    });

  }

}
```

What's happening here is that when app.js first starts, my middleware `mids.anonymousCart` is run.  In my middleware, it checks that the id of Cart model stored as `anonymous_id` exists or not.  It doesn't, so it creates the cart and stores the id.  Since this is stored in the middleware and not Express, it can be accessed by any file linked to it.

I then turned the id I got back into a string, so that it could be read in the next function's `findById`.  And if there's any items in the cart, Mongoose will then fill them in using the `populate()` method.  But THE THING TO PAY ATTENTION TO is the way the data received in `cartReady` is stored in the middleware variable `mids.cart`, which is then read by `res.locals.cart` on app.js.